# firebase app registration ERROR => no matching client found for package name

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I want to use **Firebase** in my project but says **that no matching client found for package name this error**

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   No matching client found for package name 'co.yota.flash_chat'

appears to me although my package name on **flutter project is the same at firebase**

here is the Run logs

```
Launching lib\main.dart on CAM L21 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'co.yota.flash_chat'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is most likely because you provided a different app name when firebase generated the `google-services.json`.

Make sure the `google-services.json` `client.client_info.package_name` is the same as 
`AndroidManifest.xml` `<manifest package="...">`

Answer (score 0):

I found it may happen sometimes because no reason so I made a new project and tried and it worked for me, to prevent problems merge it with your project on github

Answer (score 0):

This can be because you have placed wrong services.jason file in your project directory

the only solution might be creating a new project or replacing that wrong file with the correct one...

hope it will be useful!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is included in Approved answer, and not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers. Either edit your answer to add value or delete it altogether; this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful and not scattered/duplicated.